# wp_get_attachment_url filter won't accept two arguments

Tags: php, filters

Here is the specification for the filter for the `wp_get_attachment_url` filter:

```
/**
 * Filter the attachment URL.
 *
 * @since 2.1.0
 *
 * @param string $url     URL for the given attachment.
 * @param int    $post_id Attachment ID.
 */
```

And this is my attempted filter:

```
function mfeu_filter_attachment_url( $url, $post_id ) {
  return (get_post_meta($post_id,'_mfeu_external_url',true) != '') ? get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_attached_file',true) : $url;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url','mfeu_filter_attachment_url');
```

I am consistently getting the following errors:

```
[24-Feb-2016 21:15:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Missing argument 2 for mfeu_filter_attachment_url() in .../wp-content/plugins/media-external-url/media-external-url.php on line 20
[24-Feb-2016 21:15:55 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: post_id in .../wp-content/plugins/media-external-url/media-external-url.php on line 21
```

It seems as though the filter isn't meant to accept two arguments, even though the description in the core WordPress file `post.php` makes it seem so! My filter needs to be able to know which attachment it's dealing with in order to get the attachment's meta and use that to make a decision on how to return the url. Can anybody see what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing the number of callback input arguments, so try this one instead:

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_url','mfeu_filter_attachment_url', 10, 2 );
                                                                  |  |
                                                 Priority    _____|  |
                                      Number of arguments    ________|
```

The default is `10, 1`, so you're currently only passing on the `$url` and not the second `$post_id` argument.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Didn't even think to look in the docs for `add_filter`. Thank you!